# Access reading violation when creating a database connection

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to write a basic http server in c++, and i need to fetch information from a local database.
I'm using MySql c++ connector with the legacy API but on connection creation i receive this exception:

**Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE69031416 (vcruntime140d.dll) in HTTP_SERVER.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.**

with this code:

```cpp
    void Database_connection::connect(sql::SQLString& host, sql::SQLString& username, 
        sql::SQLString& password, sql::SQLString& DBName) {

        try {
            sql::Driver* sqlDriver = get_driver_instance();
            // enstablish connection
            if (sqlDriver != nullptr) {
                connection = sqlDriver->connect(host, username, password);
            }

            // use the given database
            connection->setSchema(DBName);
        } catch (sql::SQLException e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << " // " << e.getErrorCode() << " // " << e.getSQLState() << " // " << std::endl;
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "throwed something" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

specifically on **connection = sqlDriver->connect(host, username, password);**

Now, this only happen in release mode, in debug everything is fine; the strings host, username and password are correct, and the driver should also be fine.

Can you help me?

Comment: what is the variable `driver` ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the driver throws an exception which is *derived* from `sql::SQLException`. As you catch by value, you cannot catch derived exceptions.

Instead you should accept by reference (this is a general rule: throw by value, catch by reference). That way you get access to the `what()` string which should tell you in more details what's actually going wrong.

Additionally, `get_driver_instance` might throw an exception, too, but call to resides outside of the try-catch block.

Finally, you use a different variable `driver` (member variable? – declaration is missing) to open the connection than the one you assigned the driver object to (the object assigned to local variable is leaking!).

Comment: you mean `catch (sql::SQLException& e) ` ?, if that's the case it does not catch the exception thrown; also tried with `catch (std::exception& e)` that also doesn't catch the exception.

Comment: @LeonardoMontagner *'doesn't work'* is not very precise. What *exactly* doesn't work?

Comment: @LeonardoMontagner Note that [MySQL examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) catch by reference, too.

Comment: sorry, by not working i mean it does not catch the exception, the program just stop.

Comment: @LeonardoMontagner `get_driver_instance` call is not inside try-catch block. Added a few lines to my answer for.

Comment: driver is the class member variable i used previously, i use and defined sqlDriver for clarity and to be sure it actually gives me the driver. Changed the check to `sqlDriver != nullptr` but nothing changed, still the exception doesn't get caught

Comment: also moved `sqlDriver* driver = get_driver_instance()` in the try/catch block, still no changes

Comment: @LeonardoMontagner Having some doubts if the exception indeed is thrown within `connect` function. You can verify by `catch(...) { /*output some message*/ }`, which would catch *anything* thrown (but you don't have type information about *what* being thrown). If you don't get a message your exception is thrown elsewhere. In this case try a debugger and make it stop on exceptions. Then move up the call stack until you find the first of your own functions. You can find out the type of exception that way, too, in case of `catch(...)` was successful.

Comment: Note, too, that currently the driver object is leaking. You need to assign it to the member variable at some point of time. Make sure you still can `delete` it even if the excption is thrown from `sqlDriver->connect`. And consider `connect` being called *again* (member variable `driver` already being set; just reassigning will again produce a memory leak).

Comment: 1) `catch(...)` does catch the exception and print something (modified original post with it). 2) i already use a debugger (visual studio one, not visual studio code) that break at connection creation. 3) i don't care about sqlDriver leaking, I'm using it to fix the problem, if it works only by declaring it inside the function I'll take care of that 4) connect shouldn't be called again and it already is a member variable called once, just not in this code.

Comment: @LeonardoMontagner You don't need to declare it inside function. You can assign to member variable directly. Original error was about using two different variables, local one being assigned, the other one (member) being used afterwards. Have you linked against debug version of sql library? If so, you should be able to see the exception being created when debugger stops.

Comment: The error was present even before i declared sqlDriver inside the function but for clarity and to be sure it actually worked I declared another driver variable. Also the problem does not appear in debug mode (which uses the debug library), and I also tried building release mode with debug libraries without success either. Anyway thank you for helping me, I solved the problem by updating the library.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself, still don't know what the problem is but i re-downloaded release and debug libraries from [connector c++](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) and rebuild with the appropriate libraries